# possible to generate random float over closed interval [0.0,1.0]?

Tags: go, random, floating-point

Go's `rand.Float32()` and `rand.Float64()` generate a random float over a half-closed interval over [0.0, 1.0).

However, I need something that generates over an interval closed at *both* ends (i.e., [0.0,1.0]), since `1.0` needs to be a possible value in my application.

Is this possible?  Go doesn't appear to have a built-in function for this, and I haven't found any answers online.

Comment: What kind of distribution do you want?  Do you want all possible values less than 0.5 or only ones with a greater than 0.5 mate?  IOWs, could the minimum `Float32` ever occur?

Comment: Since you have `rand.Float32()`, why not double it and retry when the product > 1.0?

Comment: Further, since you want [0.0,1.0], I have doubts about the true desired distribution.  Can you post more details about the use of `[0.0,1.0]`?  IOWs `rand.Float32()` rounded to the nearest 1/(2^24) may meet your needs.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it's for a weigted die algorithm, where different rolls have different probabilities.

Comment: For a 1D6, use `Floor(rand.Float32()*6) + 1`.  For a 1D100, `Floor(rand.Float32()*100) + 1`.

Comment: If it's a weighted die, then each subinterval will also be half closed, since they can't overlap, so it seems that [0.0, 1.0) is really what you want for all intervals, including overall.

Comment: you mention the upper bound, but do you need `0` ? if you return `1.0` when the random value is exactly `0.0`, you would have a uniform distribution over `(0, 1.0]`

Answer (score 5):

fun fact: if you look at [the implementation for `rand.Float64()`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.22.0:src/math/rand/rand.go;l=189) in the standard library, they explicitly exclude the value `1` :

```
func (r *Rand) Float64() float64 {
    // A clearer, simpler implementation would be:
    //  return float64(r.Int63n(1<<53)) / (1<<53)
    // However, Go 1 shipped with
    //  return float64(r.Int63()) / (1 << 63)
    // and we want to preserve that value stream.
    //
    // There is one bug in the value stream: r.Int63() may be so close
    // to 1<<63 that the division rounds up to 1.0, and we've guaranteed
    // that the result is always less than 1.0.
    //
    // We tried to fix this by mapping 1.0 back to 0.0, but since float64
    // values near 0 are much denser than near 1, mapping 1 to 0 caused
    // a theoretically significant overshoot in the probability of returning 0.
    // Instead of that, if we round up to 1, just try again.
    // Getting 1 only happens 1/2⁵³ of the time, so most clients
    // will not observe it anyway.
again:
    f := float64(r.Int63()) / (1 << 63)
    if f == 1 {
        goto again // resample; this branch is taken O(never)
    }
    return f
}
```

you may want to try the suggestion in the comment:

```
func myRandFloat64() float64 {
    return float64(rand.Int63n(1<<53)) / (1<<53)
}

// or:
func myRandFloat64() float64 {
    return float64(rand.Int63n(1<<53 + 1)) / (1<<53)
}
```

I *think* the second version will still give an even distribution -- my reasoning is: all numbers from `0 / 1<<53` to `1<<53-1 / 1<<53` should all be distinct, and `1<<53 / 1<<53` should be exactly `1.0` and distinct from the other ones -- but floating point operations are notoriously tricky and I may have missed a detail.

---

Another option, as you wrote in your self answer, is to call `rand.Intn(sampling)` directly and choose an adequate sampling value.

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured it out!

`float64(rand.Intn(101)) / 100.00`

Comment: do you have specific needs regarding the statistical distribution ? do note for example that, in this snippet you posted, you are looking at distribution over 101 values (not over 100). 100 values would be: `float64(1 + rand.Intn(100)) / 100.0`